# VMWare Fusion crashing when opening Bootcamp

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp, vmware-fusion

I have Snow Leopard and Windows 7 Professional 64 bit (via Bootcamp) installed on a 2010 MacBook.

When I try to run Windows 7 (installed on Bootcamp) on VMWare Fusion 3, VMWare Fusion window just close and MacOS X tells me that vmware has crashed.

When I reopen it, closed windows are restored with the OS still running.

Any idea why it is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling "Pass power status to the VM" in `Settings > Advanced > Other` seems to have solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused here - When you use VMWare Fusion, you should not be using Bootcamp at all - you should just start a new Virtual Machine and install Windows as if it is a physical machine.

Bootcamp is for actually using Windows as a native Operating system on your Mac and has nothing to do with VMware Fusion.

If I have misunderstood you, please can you explain a little more about the problem and your environment.

Comment: I have Windows 7 installed on Bootcamp but I can access this partition via VMWare Fusion too. That way I can access it when booting it and when running Mac OS.
Hope I cleared things up.